# Regex replace "\n" occurrences by divide by 2

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, regexp-replace

I have string with \n

```
First\nSecond\n\nThird\n\n\n\n
```

I want after replace **(\n >=2)**, it's

```
First\nSecond\nThird\n\n
```

I would appreciate some help. Many thanks!

Comment: What should happen with odd numbers of `\n`? Such as `Blah\n\n\n` and `Blah\n\n\n\n\n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace every two `\n` with a single `\n`:

```
s.replace(/\n\n/g, '\n')
```

```js
const s = 'First\nSecond\n\nThird\n\n\n\n'

console.log(JSON.stringify(s.replace(/\n\n/g, '\n')))
```